# Ember.js - Hamburger menu disable click on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js

I am a newbee in Ember. I am designing an application that has a hamburger menu. The menu slides in as an overlay from left to right when clicking the icon. My HTML and CSS for menu component is something like this:

```css
& {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background-color: rgba(54, 53, 69, 0.65);
  @include set-z-index(LOADING_OVERLAY);
  @keyframes slideIn {
    from {
      transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
    to {
      transform: none;
    }
  }
  @keyframes slideOut {
    from {
      transform: none;
    }
    to {
      transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    }
  }
  .slideIn {
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-direction: normal;
  }
  .slideOut {
    animation-name: slideOut;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }
  .modaldiv {
    width: 17%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
  }
  .menu {
    width: 83%;
    height: 100%;
    /* rest of the menu css goes here */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modaldiv"></div>
<div class="menu slideIn">
  <!--Entire menu component goes here like user details -->
</div>
</div>
```

I have a header component that has the hamburger menu icon. The HTML and JS for it is,

```js
export default Component.extend({
      openMenu: null,
      actions: {
        menuOpen() {
          if (!this.get('openMenu')) {
            this.set('openMenu', true);
          } else {
            this.set('openMenu', false);
          }
        }
      });
```

```html
<div class="header">
  {{#if menuComponent}}
  <div class='switcher menu' onclick={{action 'menuOpen'}}>
    {{fa-icon 'bars'}} {{#if openMenu}} {{component menuComponent}} {{/if}}
  </div>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

As of now, the entire screen is clickable. I want to disable click on the menu component so that the user closes the menu by clicking outside it and it slides out.

I tried giving an action on the menu and modaldiv components,

```js
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  closeClicked = false,
  actions: {
    closeMenu() {
      this.set(this.closeClicked, true); //slide out does not work!
    }
  },
  disableclick() {
    this.$('.menu').css('pointer-events', 'none'); //does not disable the clicks on menu component. 
  },
});
```

```html
<div class="modaldiv" onclick={{action 'closeMenu'}}></div>
<div class="menu {{if closeClicked " slideOut " "slideIn "}}" onclick={{action 'disableclick'}}>
  <!--Entire menu component goes here like user details -->
</div>
</div>
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone give clarity on how I can approach this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this addon [ember-click-outside](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-click-outside) I think it does what you need.

Comment: @Alvaro Hey! Actually I am not allowed to use addons for this application.